# UNION sums of columns in 6 different tables into one column?

Tags: sql, metabase

Is it possible to union multiple aggregate columns?

I have 6 tables, each from a different subquery, which have format (User ID, Count). Each table represents a different stage that the user is in. I'm trying to create a final table with columns (Stage, Total # of Users), where the total # is the sum of the "Count" column of each stage.

So far I've left-joined all 6 tables together into a table with format (User ID, Stage 1 Count, Stage 2 Count, Stage 3 Count, etc).

I was thinking I could SELECT the sum of each Stage Count (attempted below) and then UNION them together (not sure how to do this) to "stack" them in a 2 x 7 result (Each row is [stage name], [sum of stage count] with a header row), but I'm not sure how I would structure this in my query.

I'm stuck here:

```
SELECT
   count(new_user_id),
   sum(appt_booked),
   sum(first_appt_comp),
   sum(apt_summary_viewed),
   sum(second_appt_comp),
   sum(promoter)

FROM all_users
LEFT JOIN appt_booked_users ON all_users.new_user_id = appt_booked_users.appt_user_id
LEFT JOIN appt_comp_users ON all_users.new_user_id = appt_comp_users.appt_comp_one_user_id
LEFT JOIN act_comp_users ON appt_booked_users.appt_id = act_comp_users.summary_appt_id
LEFT JOIN appt_comp_two_users ON all_users.new_user_id = appt_comp_two_users.appt_comp_two_user_id
LEFT JOIN promoter_users ON all_users.new_user_id = promoter_users.promoter_user_id
```

Comment: You can't have header row as part of your result unless you cast your aggregates as varchar and provide an ordering mechanism such that headers are at the top. Does your DB supports CTE? Please tag your DB and version

Comment: Display and formatting should be done from presentation layer not DB side.